# How many temporary variables are created in this loop?

Tags: c

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    int j;
    printf("%X\n", &j);
}
```

How many temporary variables `j` are created in this loop?

Is `j` created 5 times, or only once?

Though the address is the same..

Comment: Nitpick: use `%p` as the format placeholder for pointers.

Comment: @detly: And cast to `void*`: `printf("%p\n", (void*)&j);`

Answer (score 5):

5. Although the compiler could certainly optimize that to 1.

Comment: Correct.  The lifetime of `j` is the innermost block (`{` ... `}`) that contains its declaration.  Each time the block is executed, it *logically* creates a new instance of `j` -- just as each call to function creates new instances of each of its local variables.  But the generated code probably won't actually do anything to create and destroy `j`; most likely its storage will just be folded into the local storage for the containing function.  (But a conforming implementation *could* physically create and destroy `j` 5 times, possibly giving it a distinct address each time.)

Comment: Who marked this down?  According to the C standard, this is correct.  The compiler is allowed to reuse the same memory location, but that's just an optimization under the as-if rule.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you modified your code slightly:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int j = rand();
    printf("%5d (%p)\n", j, (void *)&j);
}
```

You would see a different value for `j` in each iteration, making it clear that `j` is given a value each time through the loop, even if the address of `j` was the same in each loop.  This would demonstrate more clearly that `j` is initialized on each iteration (and is logically created and destroyed on each iteration).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two things to mention here,

### Locality of a Variable:

The locality of the variable `j` is the next '`}`'. When the program approaches the bracket, the variable `j` dies.

### Temporal Locality:

There is a mechanism in computers that they tend to keep the extensively used variables and prevent them from dying because they might be needed again. So it is very much possible that the computer will in real not generate the variable `j` `5` times.

### Conclusion:

As far as the answer to your question is concerned so you can say 5 as the person who wanted asked you this question wanted you to get an idea about locality of a variable.